# How to move Eclipse project to Netbeans IDE

Tags: eclipse, netbeans

There is `MyProject` folder in my eclipse workspace. It consist of gui class and main class. I want to move this project to Netbeans IDE. Because I think Eclipse's Window builder is awkward to design gui and has weaker function than netbeans one. Anyway, when I move to file to Netbeans , I couldn't see the tab named `GUI` that easily move/add/delete components. The only I can see, just a code.

How to move my gui class to Netbeans IDE? I want to add/delete swing components in there. How can I do that?

I found **Import eclipse proect** . However, I can't manipluate my gui in Netbeans GUI Builder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you will need to recreate the GUI panels in netbeans.

Netbeans doesn't support 2 way editing of forms, it stores and read the data from the .form file and regenerates parts of the java file on changes.